# Current IP Of LDAP Host In Round Robin IP selection

Tags: php, ldap

I have a LDAP server ( for example ldaps://abc.example.com).
I am using @ldap_connect() function and program in PHP for getting connection with ldap. This host has more than one ips configured for it and uses them in round robin fashion. So is there any way by which I can get the current ip with whom currently its connected from within these ips?

Code:

```
$host = "ldaps://abc.example.com";
$binddn = "cn=user,ou=My Accounts,ou=TestUsers,ou=Test System   access,dc=abc,dc=example,dc=com";
$password = "xyz"
for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ )
{
    $conn = @ldap_connect( $host );
    if ( !$conn )
    {
        sleep(1);
        continue;
    }
    echo "Connected at $host (my attempt count is $i): ";
    print_r($conn, true);
    @ldap_set_option( $conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 );
    @ldap_set_option( $conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0 );
    echo "Binding at $host (my attempt count is $i)";
    $Resource = @ldap_bind( $conn, $binddn, $password );
    if ( $Resource )
    {
        break;
    }
    echo "Bind failed to AD at $host (my attempt count is $i): " . trim (@ldap_error($conn);
    @ldap_close( $conn );
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you. I edited your code. Please think to indent it, ext time.

Answer (score 0):

As you will only be connecting to the same `A` record, you could just use the `gethostbyname()` function to give you the IP of the connected server. You would then use `gethostbyaddr()` to perform a reverse lookup (IP to Hostname) to grab the `PTR` record. This variable assigned to `gethostbyaddr()` would be the hostname you would use for making the LDAP query as you are technically not querying the `A` record, but the IP address which in-turn bypasses round robin.

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.google.com'); //Get the ip via hostname (Given IP from Round Robin)
$address = gethostbyaddr($ip); // Convert the IP to Hostname using reverse lookup/ PTR Lookup

echo $address; //Use this for your LDAP query
```

In my example above, Google has a different `PTR` record (Reverse Lookup Record) to the `A` record so in this instance, the result is different to my original query of `www` and shows the hostname as *lhr35s01-in-f4.1e100.net*. If you control your DNS (which I'm guessing you do), you could create a `PTR` record which matches the `A` record so your reverse lookup resolves correctly.

**Output:**

```
lhr35s01-in-f4.1e100.net
```

*See:*

*http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php*

*http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php*

Comment: Thanks Kitson for reply

Comment: gethostbyname() function is getting ip from ips list and it called seperately from @ldap_connect(), we are using round robin way of providing ip on call so possiblity of getting different ips during calls is high by both functions.
 gethostbyname() function is getting ip from ips list and it called seperately from @ldap_connect(), we are using round robin way of providing ip on call so possiblity of getting different ips during calls is high by both functions.

Comment: You could query the IP via host name first, then perform a reverse lookup to get the true host name because round robin will only present an IP when the host name is queried and not when the specific IP is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know to which server you are connecting, my solution would be to turn things around.

```
$dclist = gethostbynamel($host); // will get the list of IPs in round robin fashion (order changes)

$host = $dc[0]; // will contain different IP

// now you can connect to $host while knowing the IP...
```

(this might not work with ssl tho.. sorry about that, I just now noticed you do connect using ldaps...)